# numpy delete rows not in list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Here is my code to delete given row numbers

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(6, 2)
b = [1, 4]
a: [[ 0  1]
 [ 2  3]
 [ 4  5]
 [ 6  7]
 [ 8  9]
 [10 11]]
```

then i delete the lines in b :

```
np.delete(a, b, 0)

output : 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [10, 11]])
```

I want to use this logic to only keep the rows in b, and do the reverse operation without any loop.
so expected output will be :

```
output: [
 [ 2,  3]
 [ 8,  9]
 ]
```

Comment: Why do you want to delete the rows? why not use a[b] to accses the part you need? You can get the desired result by a=a[b]

Comment: `np.delete` internally figures out which rows you want to keep, and returns those.  So keeping the the `b` rows is actually simpler - conceptually and computationally.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, splitting the array `a` using the indices in `b`:

```
a2 = a[b]
a1 = np.delete(a,b,0)
```

output:

```
# a1
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [10, 11]])

# a2
array([[2, 3],
       [8, 9]])
```

restoring the original array from `a1`, `a2`, and `b`:

```
idx = np.arange(a1.shape[0]+a2.shape[0])
idx = np.r_[np.delete(idx,b,0),idx[b]]

new_a = np.r_[a1,a2][np.argsort(idx)]
```

output:

```
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is just to keep the wanted rows in b by doing:

```
x = a[b,:]
```

Don't delete unwanted rows but just select the needed one